# How to hide code argument during this code evaluation in specific scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

Is it possible to make arg "code" inaccessible/invisible, while maintaining the availability of global objects (e.g. window and document) and arg "scope"?
First and second log should display information while third one should thow an exception.

```js
var foo;

function reg(scope, code) {
    eval(code);
}

reg(
    {test: "test"},
    'foo = function(){console.log("Window:", window); console.log("Scope:", scope); console.log("Code:", code);}'
);
foo();
```

Comment: First suggestion, don't use `eval` and don't convert text to code.

Comment: If you can access it via `window.code`, then calling just `code` would call same `window.code`. Can you explain what you try to do?

Comment: @Justinas `eval` runs the code in the current scope, that's why it can see `code`.

Comment: @Justinas I want to raise small environment to run user's code in browser. I want to reveal some arguments and properties but hide code text.

Comment: What about `eval('code = undefined; ' + code);`?

Comment: @Justinas works for me. So simple - I can’t believe that I couldn’t guess about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unset that attribute inside eval:

```
eval('code = undefined; ' + code);
```